# Android enable and disable GPS automatically every time app asks for location from background with tasker

Tags: android, gps, geolocation, tasker

I want to use an app that tracks my location every one hour. The app runs in background and I wanted to ask if there is a way to make the `GPS` to be turned on Every time the app asks for location from background and after it gets the location, it makes the `GPS` turned off in order to save battery life.
I tried to use `tasker` but it works only when I open and close the app. It doesn't function when the app asks for location from the background.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To save battery, you could use [requestSingleUpdate](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate%28java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on `LocationManager` and set an alarm every hour with [setInexactRepeating](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) on `AlarmManager`.

Comment: Is this the best method?
I need it to be synced with the app so it will turn on GPS when the app requests and I didn't see an option for this in the link you've provided,
Thanks!

Comment: @Ofirk, sorry it's not very clear, do you want to "enable" GPS programmatically, if it's disabled in android settings ?

Comment: I want that every time the tracking app (which runs in background) asks for location the phone will recognize that, enable GPS and disable it right after the app gets the location.

Comment: If user enabled GPS in android settings and no applications request location, then GPS is in "sleep mode". As soon as 1 app request for location then GPS start to get a location.

Answer (score 1):

there is a common misconception about the `GPS` setting, that having it enabled, drains battery.

It is not necessarily true.

When `WiFi` is turned on, it scans for signal every once in a while, or is transmitting data (also in the bacground, if not disabled in the settings)

However with `GPS`, as mentioned by `LaurentY`, situation is entirely different, as location is being checked **only** if requested, so it makes no sense to have it disabled and then toggle it every time an app needs it. Especially on Android 6.0 where you can manage per-app permissions (disable `GPS` access to all non-essential apps and allow only that one).

you can also have Tasker check your location at predefined time intervals, not having to use that app you mentioned before

Comment: Really good point this  would be interesting to see if anything set up ans documented, re tests, results... And method... Adding to list (todos: taskertestprofiles )

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly you can't disable/enable GPS programatically without user accept. If you want to enable GPS programatically, User should be notified about that and he should accept GPS enabling. I think in your choice you can just set minimum required time to get User position using requestLocationUpdates

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 60000, 5, locationListener);
```

In this choice GPS will be used each 60000 milliseconds , but it would be enabled all time. In this way you will save your bettery life.

Comment: Thanks! Can you specify how to enable GPS programatically with asking user acceptance?

Comment: see this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/